# Jupyter Notebook/PyTorch, module 'torch' has no attribute 'BoolTensor'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I am working in PyTorch and I need to use a BoolTensor, which is available according to the documentation https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html

However, when I try to initialize the BoolTensor I get the error: "AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'BoolTensor'"

All other tensors do work normally, like LongTensor or DoubleTensor

I have no idea what could cause this particular error, since it seems pretty strange that only one type of tensor doesn't work to me...

Comment: What version of PyTorch are you using? You can see with: `print(torch.__version__)`. I think you need PyTorch `1.2` or later to use them.

Answer (score 0):

please use  `torch.ByteTensor` instead of `torch.BoolTensor`